# Uneven Circles in Connect 4 Board

Tags: c++, winapi, math, gdi+

I'm in the process of creating a 2P Connect 4 game, but I can't seem to get the circular areas to place tokens spaced evenly.

Here's the code that initializes the positions of each circle:

```
POINT tilePos;

for (int i = 0; i < Board::Dims::MAXX; ++i) 
{
    tileXY.push_back (std::vector<POINT> (Board::Dims::MAXY)); //add column

    for (int j = 0; j < Board::Dims::MAXY; ++j)
    {
        tilePos.x = boardPixelDims.left + (i + 1./2) * (boardPixelDims.width / Board::Dims::MAXX);
            tilePos.y = boardPixelDims.top + (j + 1./2) * (boardPixelDims.height / Board::Dims::MAXY);

        tileXY.at (i).push_back (tilePos); //add circle in column
    }
}
```

I use a 2D vector of `POINT`s, `tileXY`, to store the positions. Recall the board is 7 circles wide by 6 circles high.

My logic is such that the first circle starts (for X) at:

```
left + width / #circles * 0 + width / #circles / 2
```

and increases by `width / #circles` each time, which is easy to picture for smaller numbers of circles.

Later, I draw the circles like this:

```
for (const std::vector<POINT> &col : _tileXY)
{
    for (const POINT pos : col)
    {
        if (g.FillEllipse (&red, (int)(pos.x - CIRCLE_RADIUS), pos.y - CIRCLE_RADIUS, CIRCLE_RADIUS, CIRCLE_RADIUS) != Gdiplus::Status::Ok)
            MessageBox (_windows.gameWindow, "FillEllipse failed.", 0, MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
    }
}
```

Those loops iterate through each element of the vector and draws each circle in red (to stand out at the moment). The int conversion is to disambiguate the function call. The first two arguments after the brush are the top-left corner, and `CIRCLE_RADIUS` is 50.

The problem is that my board looks like this (sorry if it hurts your eyes a bit):

[image: The circles are too far up and left.]

As you can see, the circles are too far up and left. They're also too small, but that's easily fixed. I tried changing some ints to doubles, but ultimately ended up with this being the closest I ever got to the real pattern. The expanded formula (expanding (i + 1./2)) for the positions looks the same as well.

Have I missed a small detail, or is my whole logic behind it off?

**Edit:**
As requested, types:

`tilePos.x`: POINT (the windows API one, type used is LONG)
`boardPixelDims.*`: double
`Board::Dims::MAXX/MAXY`: enum values (integral, contain 7 and 6 respectively)

Comment: What are the types of `tilePos.x`,`boardPixelDims.left`,`boardPixelDims.width`,`Board::Dims::MAXX`,`tilePos.y` ,`boardPixelDims.top`,`boardPixelDims.height`, `Board::Dims::MAXY`?

Comment: @JamesCuster, I added the requested types at the bottom. `tilePos` shouldn't be a problem seeing as how it can only be off by <1px from the code. It stores the final result.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to make sure `(boardPixelDims.width / Board::Dims::MAXX)` wasn't a problem.

Comment: @JamesCuster, I realized that when the top left circle appeared on the outside corner of the board. More specifically, it was `(i + 1/2)` causing that one. Kind of annoying how it's hard to make small, compilable test cases when you use the Windows API for drawing etc >.>

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `pos.x - CIRCLE_SIZE/2` and `pos.y - CIRCLE_SIZE/2` in the FillEllipse call?  It looks like your code is defining the center of the circles, so you want to shift by CIRCLE_SIZE/2 when calling FillEllipse.

Comment: @happydave, sorry about that. `CIRCLE_SIZE` is already tuned to this as it's the only thing it's being used for. I'll change it to radius instead.

Comment: Actually, @happydave, that solved my problem! I realized when I changed it that the width and height of the ellipse should be `CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2`. I'll give you credit for that one if you make it into an answer. I also feel like an idiot now -__-

Comment: For those who have acute perception, I did accidentally add two boards worth of columns, half of them empty due to passing the size of each column I added and then pushing onto it. There was a previously invisible circle located at (0,0). @happydave, I still await your answer. I know you want the rep and your comment was the precursor to the solution.

Comment: @chris - okay, if you insist.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether CIRCLE_SIZE is intended as radius or diameter, two of your parameters seem to be wrong in the FillEllipse call.  If it's a diameter, then you should be setting location to `pos.x - CIRCLE_SIZE/2` and `pos.y - CIRCLE_SIZE/2`.  If it's a radius, then the height and width paramters should each be 2*CIRCLE_SIZE rather than CIRCLE_SIZE.

Update - since you changed the variable name to CIRCLE_RADIUS, the latter solution is now obviously the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I remember what arguments the shape related functions take is to always think in rectangles.  FillEllipse will just draw an ellipse to fill the rectangle you give it. x, y, width and height.

A simple experiment to practice with is if you change your calls to FillRect, get everything positioned okay, and then change them to FillEllipse.

Comment: I do like the `FillRectangle` idea. In this case, I just mixed up what the dimensions were supposed to be in relation to my constant.